# Why is Http code 500 returned although I catch the exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Although my if-clause is executed in my fiddler I see the http error 500 and not 404, why is that?

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is ResourceNotFoundException)
            {
                context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, context.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                base.Handle(context); 
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I get in the fiddler Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 3945
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2015 08:14:45 GMT

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The Resource could not be found!","ExceptionType":"ErpApplicationEndpoints.ResourceNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   at  ... Removed for clarity...
```

Comment: your custom handler is getting executed?

Comment: yes just like I have written the if-clause is executed!

Comment: I updated my question with the fiddler response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Result` property on the `ExceptionHandlerContext` object in your if clause instead of doing `CreateErrorResponse`(also this is incorrect as your not assigning the created `HttpResponseMessage` to anything)

`context.Result = <a-httpactionresult-instance-here>`

Comment: So to get an IHttpActionResult instance I have to implement this interface in a custom class? OR should it not be this => context.Response =
                    context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, errorMessagError);

Comment: Ah... this last code is from an ExceptionFilter !!! The ExceptionHandler does not have context.Response, just context.Request or context.Result WHY ???